# Not able to convert from PScustomobject to Arraylist

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to get all the list of patches from multiple servers. I am using invoke command with -asjob parameter to get the patch list from all servers.  Running the below code. 
I am getting the below error. I have tried with

```
Get-CIMInstance -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering
```

and with

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering
```

but keep getting same error.

```
$Servers = Get-Content "C:\Users\Suman.Ghosh\Servers.txt"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$All_Jobs = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Updated_Servers_List = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Jobs_Output = @()

$Patches_to_lookfor = @(
    'KB4462926',
    'KB4462941'
)

foreach ($S in $Servers) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $S -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $Updated_Servers_List += $S
        $All_Jobs += Invoke-Command -ComputerName $S -ScriptBlock {Get-HotFix} -AsJob
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Computer $S is not running"
    }
}

Write-Host "below Jobs are running" -ForegroundColor Cyan
$All_Jobs

Write-Host "waiting for jobs to finish" -ForegroundColor Cyan
$All_Jobs | Wait-Job

$temp = @()
$flag = $false
foreach ($job in $All_Jobs) {
    $Jobs_Output += Get-Job $job.Id | Receive-Job | Select HotFixID, CSNAME
}

foreach ($Job_output in $Jobs_Output) {
    Write-Host $Job_output -ForegroundColor Green
    ### DO some stuff
}
```

```
Cannot convert value "@{HotFixID=KB4020449; CSName=mit1epxa2}" to type
"System.Collections.ArrayList".
Error: "Cannot convert the "@{HotFixID=KB4020449; CSName=mit1epxa2}" value
of type "Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type
"System.Collections.ArrayList"."
At line:1 char:10
+ foreach ($Job_output in $Jobs_Output) {
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Comment: Did you check how the `$Jobs_Output` variable? Does it look as expected?

Comment: `Write-Host $Job_output.HotfixID $Job_output.CSName` (`$Job_output` is still an object with two properties)

Comment: on win7ps5.1 this code `$Jobs_Output += ` usually converts your arraylist to a standard array. are you sure that your `$Jobs_Output` variable is of the type that you expect? what is the `.GetType()` result of both `$Jobs_Output` and `$Job_Output`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's see if my second answer gets deleted (with no notification) by people who don't know the topic.  I believe you have run a command like this on $job_output (no "s"):

```
[collections.arraylist]$job_output = @()
```

Then in the loop at the bottom, an exception is created because a pscustomobject can't be cast to a collections.arraylist with the $job_output variable.  $jobs_output (with the "s") is an arraylist of [pscustomobjects]'s created by select.

```
foreach ($Job_output in $Jobs_Output) {
    Write-Host $Job_output -ForegroundColor Green
    ### DO some stuff
}
```